# Simple CSS Solution for Decorative Line Under Title

Tags: html, css

I am working on a restaurant website. Each area of the menu will have a title and below it the dishes in that section. There is a decorative line under the row of the title that stretches the width of the column. The decorative line, however, does not appear under the text. I am wondering how I would be able to achieve this effect?

I only have one solution, but I am looking for an even simpler solution. I would divide the Title row into three sections: `.left-line`, `.title`, and `.right-line`. Both `.left-line` and `.right-line` will contain the background image of the decorative line. `.title` will only contain the text. Can anyone think of a cleaner solution? The html would be:

```
<p class="left-line"></p>
<p class="title">Appetizer</p>
<p class="right-line"></p>
```

[image: Sample of Design]

Comment: `::before/::after` pseudo elements?

Comment: If you don't need to support old IE browsers, you could use pseudo elements to mimic your left and right elements. Edit: @steveax beat me to it. :)

Comment: Yup. I'm looking into use those :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Must use Pseudo elements `:after` and `:before` to make line after and before.

CSS

```css
body {
  background:url(http://www.hdiphonewallpaper.com/uploads/image/Light%20Background/IPhone%204%20Background%20color.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.container {
  width:250px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.title{
  line-height:2em;
  font-family:arial;
  text-align:left;
  float:left;
}

.title:before {
 content: "";
 // background: url("icon.jpg") no-repeat;
 border-bottom:2px solid #000;
 width: 40px;
 height: 20px;
 float: left;
 margin: -6px 5px 0 0;
}

.title:after {
 content: "";
 // background: url("icon.jpg") no-repeat;
 border-bottom:2px solid #000;
 width:100%;
 height: 20px;
 margin: -6px 0px 0 5px;
 position:absolute;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<span class="title">APPERTIZER</span>
  <br style="clear:both">
Salad-Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
Salad-Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
Salad-Lorem ipsum dolor sit

<span class="title">ENTREE</span>
  <br style="clear:both">
Salad-Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
Salad-Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
Salad-Lorem ipsum dolor sit

<span class="title">DESSERT</span>
  <br style="clear:both">
Salad-Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
Salad-Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
Salad-Lorem ipsum dolor sit
  
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/sikotadufo/2/edit

Comment: I am wondering if it is possible for your answer to make it so that the right line starts right after the text of the title ends, and that the right line stops at the end of the line?

Comment: @Jon, Ooops... I didn't recognized that while coding. I have edited the answer. Now it looks same as you require.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements. You may need to give it a height / width:

```
.title::before {
    background-image: /* your image */;
    height: 1em;
    width: 2em;
}
```

The cool thing with these is it doesn't require extraneous HTML elements.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that `<p class="titile">` should be replaced with something more semantic like `h2`.

Comment: Thanks! I've been playing around the those pseudo elements now.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.left-line,.right-line{display:block;width:200px;background:#EEE;float:left;}
.left-line {width:50px;}
.title{float:left;}
```

```html
<p>
<div class="left-line">-</div>
<div class="title">Appetizer</div>
<div class="right-line">-</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</p>
```

you can try this code .

Comment: Thank you, but I was hoping for a solution that would not involve me adding additional elements such as line-left and line-right